# Are the following groups isomorphic $C_{36}\times C_9\times C_4$, $C_6\times C_6\times C_{36}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My attempt:-

First we have $C_9\times C_4 \cong C_{36}$ since $(4,9)=1$. Hence $C_{36}\times C_9\times C_4 \cong C_{36} \times C_{36}$ which means it have a element of order 36 ( which is $(1,1)$) but the other group $C_6\times C_6\times C_{36}$ have no element of order 36.

is my solution is right? because when i look at (1,1,1) in the second group it seem to have order 36 too.

Comment: It *seems* to have order 36? Have you computed its order?

Comment: What is the order of $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: You are right. That element also has order $36$. You would need to count them (the number of elements of order $35$ are different in the two groups). In that regard, it may be better to count the number of elements of order $2$. Also, when you write $C_{36}$, usually $1$ denotes the *unit* element.

Comment: the order of $(0,0,1)$ is also 36.

Comment: okay..... I get the idea now.. in first group we have only one element of order 36. but in the second one we have more than one ( (1,1,1),(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(0,0,1) ). is that right?

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's not correct. In $C_{36}$ you have several elements of order $36$.